# When I use PreferredSizeWidget in flutter I got some error with the CupertinoNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter

```
**main.dart** 

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './widgets/transaction_list.dart';
import './widgets/new_transaction.dart';
import './widgets/chart.dart';
import './models/transaction.dart';

void main() {
  // WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  //   DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  //   DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  // ]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Personal Expenses',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        accentColor: Colors.amber,
        fontFamily: "Quicksand",
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
              headline6: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 18,
              ),
              button: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "OpenSans",
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // late String titleInput;
  // late String amountInput;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [];

  List<Transaction> get _recentTransaction {
    return _userTransactions.where((tx) {
      return tx.date.isAfter(
        DateTime.now().subtract(
          Duration(days: 7),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  bool _showChart = false;

  void _addNewTransaction(
      String txTitle, double txAmount, DateTime chosenDate) {
    final newTx = Transaction(
      title: txTitle,
      amount: txAmount,
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
      date: chosenDate,
    );

    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  void _startAddNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: ctx,
      builder: (_) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: NewTransaction(_addNewTransaction),
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _deleteTransaction(String id) {
    setState(() {
      _userTransactions.removeWhere((tx) {
        return tx.id == id;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final isLandScape = mediaQuery.orientation == Orientation.landscape;
    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoNavigationBar(
            middle: Text(
              "Personal Expenses",
            ),
            trailing: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
                  onTap: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        : AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Personal Expenses',
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              )
            ],
          );
    final txListWidget = Container(
      height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
              appBar.preferredSize.height -
              mediaQuery.padding.top) *
          0.7,
      child: TransactionList(_userTransactions, _deleteTransaction),
    );

    final pageBody = SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          if (isLandScape)
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Show chart"),
                Switch.adaptive(
                  activeColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                  value: _showChart,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _showChart = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          if (!isLandScape)
            Container(
              height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                      appBar.preferredSize.height -
                      mediaQuery.padding.top) *
                  0.3,
              child: Chart(_recentTransaction),
            ),
          if (!isLandScape) txListWidget,
          if (isLandScape)
            _showChart
                ? Container(
                    height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                            appBar.preferredSize.height -
                            mediaQuery.padding.top) *
                        0.7,
                    child: Chart(_recentTransaction),
                  )
                : txListWidget,
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoPageScaffold(
            child: pageBody,
            navigationBar: appBar,
          )
        : Scaffold(
            appBar: appBar,
            body: pageBody,
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
            floatingActionButton: Platform.isIOS
                ? Container()
                : FloatingActionButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () => _startAddNewTransaction(context),
                  ),
          );
  }
}
```

While I was using the final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = Platforn.isISO ? CupertinoNavigationBar() : AppBar();

it shows me the error in this and also in CupertinoPageScaffold(child: (), navigationBar: appBar).

The error shows me in the code is: **A value of type 'Widget' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'PreferredSizeWidget'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'PreferredSizeWidget'.**

How can I solve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you create a separate AppbarTop Widget for yourself. The basis for doing this is in the snippet below, add your own logic and assign this to the `appBar` property of your `Scaffold`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppbarTop extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const AppbarTop();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Platform.isIOS ? CupertinoNavigationBar() : AppBar();
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(AppBar().preferredSize.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `PreferredSizeWidget` on `appBar` variable then then on right Hand side explicitly convert it to PreferredSizeWidget as shown in picture:[Image will help you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJxBP.png)

After that when using for CupertinoPageScaffold use `as ObstructingPreferredSizeWidget` in navigationBar [As Shown in given picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PelJs.png)

Hope if helped ;-)...